# convert a list of lm output to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, output, lm

I need to convert a list into a data frame. My list contains output of a lm function run by day and is a large list containing 521 elements.

I tried the following code:

`df <- bind_rows(modelsT, .id = "column_label")`

but I get this error:

`Error: Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a lm`

is there a way to resolve the error? Or another option how to convert a list into a data frame?

Comment: try `as.data.frame(summary(modelsT)$coefficients)`

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need:

```r
model <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
coef(model)
# (Intercept)        disp 
# 29.59985476 -0.04121512 

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(coef(model), coef(model))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   `(Intercept)`    disp
#           <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1          29.6 -0.0412
# 2          29.6 -0.0412
```

And as @jay.sf just suggested

```r
coef(summary(model))
#                Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411 3.576586e-21
# disp        -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152 9.380327e-10
bind_rows(as.data.frame(coef(summary(model))), as.data.frame(coef(summary(model))))
#      Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# 1 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411 3.576586e-21
# 2 -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152 9.380327e-10
# 3 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411 3.576586e-21
# 4 -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152 9.380327e-10
```

In general, if you want to get something `data.frame`-like out of a structure, take a look at its `str`ucture. It can be confusing, but

```r
str(model)
# List of 12
#  $ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 29.5999 -0.0412
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "disp"
#  $ residuals    : Named num [1:32] -2.01 -2.01 -2.35 2.43 3.94 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
#  $ effects      : Named num [1:32] -113.65 -28.44 -1.79 2.65 3.92 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "(Intercept)" "disp" "" "" ...
#  $ rank         : int 2
#  $ fitted.values: Named num [1:32] 23 23 25.1 19 14.8 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
#  $ assign       : int [1:2] 0 1
#  $ qr           :List of 5
#   ..$ qr   : num [1:32, 1:2] -5.657 0.177 0.177 0.177 0.177 ...
#   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
#   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "disp"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:2] 0 1
#   ..$ qraux: num [1:2] 1.18 1.09
#   ..$ pivot: int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
#   ..$ rank : int 2
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
#  $ df.residual  : int 30
#  $ xlevels      : Named list()
#  $ call         : language lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
#  $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ disp
#   .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, disp)
#   .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mpg" "disp"
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "disp"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "disp"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#   .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, disp)
#   .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mpg" "disp"
#  $ model        :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#   ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ disp
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, disp)
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
#   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mpg" "disp"
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "disp"
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "disp"
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, disp)
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
#   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mpg" "disp"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

and

```r
str(summary(model))
# List of 11
#  $ call         : language lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
#  $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ disp
#   .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, disp)
#   .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mpg" "disp"
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "disp"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "disp"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#   .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, disp)
#   .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mpg" "disp"
#  $ residuals    : Named num [1:32] -2.01 -2.01 -2.35 2.43 3.94 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
#  $ coefficients : num [1:2, 1:4] 29.59985 -0.04122 1.22972 0.00471 24.07041 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "disp"
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
#  $ aliased      : Named logi [1:2] FALSE FALSE
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "disp"
#  $ sigma        : num 3.25
#  $ df           : int [1:3] 2 30 2
#  $ r.squared    : num 0.718
#  $ adj.r.squared: num 0.709
#  $ fstatistic   : Named num [1:3] 76.5 1 30
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "value" "numdf" "dendf"
#  $ cov.unscaled : num [1:2, 1:2] 1.43e-01 -4.85e-04 -4.85e-04 2.10e-06
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "disp"
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "disp"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.lm"
```

Shows you what the individual things look like, and anything that's `matrix`-like can be easily converted with `as.data.frame()` (optionally with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`).

Comment: Thank you! I get this error `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` How can I resolve this. I tried this one `bind_rows(as.data.frame(coef(summary(model))), as.data.frame(coef(summary(model))))` as well as this one `bind_rows(coef(model), coef(model))`both return the same error

Comment: I don't know how you created your model, so I don't know how to tell you to fix it. Please make this question more *reproducible*, including sample data and code to create a model. (It doesn't have to be a meaningful model, just a model from the same tools.)

Comment: also `broom::tidy(model)`

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of the [{broom} package](https://broom.tidymodels.org/articles/broom.html), converting lm models to a data frame is a lot easier.

```r
library(broom)
library(purrr)

model <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

map_df(list(model, model, model), tidy)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21
#> 2 disp         -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10
#> 3 (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21
#> 4 disp         -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10
#> 5 (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21
#> 6 disp         -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: or even `map_dfr( ..., .id = "model")` (most useful with a *named* list of models)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the following code:

`coef <- ldply(modelsT, coef)`

Comment: For those not familiar, I suspect this is [`plyr::ldply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/ldply).